# Makefile for AVR

Tags: gcc, makefile, avr, avr-gcc

I have folder "I2C AtMega32":

[image: folder tree]

and I have my simply Makefile:

```
all: main.hex program clean

main.o: main.cpp BMP280_driver-master\bmp280.c
    avr-gcc -Wall -Os -mmcu=atmega32 -c $< -o $@

main.elf: main.o
    avr-gcc -Wall -Os -mmcu=atmega32 -o main.elf main.o

main.hex: main.elf
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf main.hex
    avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega32 main.elf

program:
#program uC

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm main.o main.elf
```

During the makefile working there is some errors:

[image: some errors here]

Why it is no working?

Comment: Having target all build clean is a huge red flag. Don't. Second, your main.o rule doesn't build bmp280.c. You should build a separate bmp280.o target for that. Read the docs on built-in rules and pattern rules.

Comment: Please don't post text as images.  You should copy and paste it and format it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is it looks like you are trying to compile two different compilation units into one object file.  I would be surprised if GCC supports that, since I've never seen it before.    Compile an object with `gcc` for each C source file, then compile an object with `g++` for each C++ source file, then link them all together.

Also note that `$<` is just the name of the first prerequisite (`main.cpp`) so you never even attempted to compile the bmp280 code.  Pay attention carefully to the commands your Makefile is running when you want to debug your build.

By the way, the `all` target should just build your HEX file.  You can run `make program` or `make clean` separately to perform those tasks, and the `program` target should of course depend on `main.hex`.